# His objection only takes (SOMETHING) with one aspect of the theory

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests, construction

I am talking about how an author notes the problem in only one aspect of a theory. I know there exists a construction on the lines of "takes notice", but is more apt here.

What is that construction?

Comment: Probably the idiom you want is _take exception with_, which means to disagree with.

Comment: Another frequently used phrase in this type of situation is ""takes issue with"—that is, "challenges."

Comment: @SvenYargs - Good thinking, that really does make sense. However it doesn't mean 'takes notice'.

Comment: @uuser142267 - There is a problem with your question. The title suggests one type of idiom (e.g. takes issue with) but later you want it to mean 'take note'.  These are not the same. Could you clarify what you mean? Thanks.

Comment: I actually mean take issue with/take exception with. I say on the lines of "take notice" to mean that the construction is similar to "take notice", not that the meaning of the construction is similar to "take notice". Sorry if that was confusing :/

Comment: If you decide to go with _exception_ as your fill-in-the-blank word, note that, according to [this Ngram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=take+exception+with%2C+take+exception+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2005&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctake%20exception%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctake%20exception%20to%3B%2Cc0), "take exception to" is a much more common formulation than "take exception with" in the Google Books database of published works.

Comment: By an even greater margin, "take issue with" is more common than "take issue to," according to [this Ngram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=take+issue+with%2Ctake+issue+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2005&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctake%20issue%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctake%20issue%20to%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 1):

In the title you say:

> His objection only takes (SOMETHING) with one aspect of the theory.

I think you mean:

His objection only takes account of one aspect of the theory

Comment: Yup, that's what it could mean, too. Though the preposition is different, that's easily misheard.

Comment: I'm beginning to wonder. My version is grammatical but I'm not sure when it could be used. Your version makes better sense  but doesn't fit with the requirement that it should mean 'taking note'.  I think we need clarification.

Comment: I think take issue/take exception most closely match what I wanted to say. Sorry about the confusion.